# Error running XUnit tests in VS2013 / ReSharper 8 - xunit.dll not found

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, xunit, xunit.net, resharper-8.0

I've upgraded all the xUnit NuGet packages in my solution to XUnit 2.1 in the hope of fixing some problems I had running my xUnit tests, but I'm getting the same problem as before, which is:

> [Window Title]
>   Unit Test Runner
>
> [Main Instruction]
>   **Unit Test Runner failed to run tests**
>
> [Content]
>   System.ArgumentException: **Could not find file**: C:\Users\myuser\mysolution\myproject\bin\Debug\ **xunit.dll**
>
> [Expanded Information]
>      at Xunit.ExecutorWrapper..ctor(String assemblyFilename, String configFilename, Boolean shadowCopy)
>      at XunitContrib.Runner.ReSharper.RemoteRunner.TestRunner.Run(XunitTestAssemblyTask assemblyTask, TaskProvider taskProvider)
>      at XunitContrib.Runner.ReSharper.RemoteRunner.XunitTaskRunner.ExecuteRecursive(TaskExecutionNode node)
>      at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode node)

I've tried un-installing, re-installing, cleaning and rebuilding, etc. etc. for hours and got nowhere.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 update 5, ReSharper 8.2.1, and have installed the following NuGet packages:

```
<package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.MSBuild" version="2.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" developmentDependency="true" />
<package id="xunit.runner.msbuild" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

To be fair, there *is* no file called `xunit.dll` in the `bin` folder, but... I've installed everything I can find, and I'm at a loss as to what else I can do.

Suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Did you try the [resharper plugin](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/xunitcontrib/)? (however it stopped working for me in recent xunit versions too so backed to the VS test runner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update Resharper extensions for XUnit, I had the same error and I had to do Resharper > Extension Manager > Updates you will see that you have one XUnit update after updating restart visual studio and it should run your tests.

Comment: I'll take your word for it - I've moved on to another project now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is possibly out of date (or a red herring) for me the issue was due to not having (as the error stated) xunit.execution*.dll ... once I located that and copied it in all was well  :)